# Hibernating Samsung S3 using commands

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I'm working on an android app related to hibernation and I want to test it using adb commands.
I tried searching but was unable to find how to hibernate/unhibernate Samsung Galaxy S3 using command line. Need help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "hibernate", you mean lock/unlock, you should be able to simulate the power button(`KEYCODE_POWER`):

```
adb shell input keyevent 26
```